# Issue with Qsort-ing a Struct

Tags: c, struct, qsort

So I've opened a CSV file, and added it to a struct. I now want to sort the struct by it's U values from lowest to highest. What I've done somewhat works but it's swapping values that aren't meant to be swapped, for example x and y, but still sorting by U.
My Struct -

```
typedef struct {
    float xvalue;
    float yvalue;
    float uvalue;
    float vvalue;
} flow_data;

int num_compare(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const flow_data *p1 = (flow_data *)v1;
    const flow_data *p2 = (flow_data *)v2;
    if (p1->uvalue < p2->uvalue)
        return -1;
    else if (p1->uvalue > p2->uvalue)
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Where I run the code -

```
FILE* fp = fopen(flow_file, "r");

// Checking if the file has been read succesfully
if( fp == NULL)
{
    perror("Error opening file");
    exit(1);
}

char buf[500];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp); // Skip the first line

int total = 0;
flow_data d;
flow_data* dataset = NULL;

while(4 == fscanf(fp, "%f, %f, %f, %f\n", &d.xvalue, &d.yvalue, &d.uvalue, &d.vvalue))
{
    dataset = realloc(dataset, sizeof(*dataset) * (total + 1));
    dataset[total] = d;
    total++;
}

qsort(dataset, total, sizeof(dataset), num_compare);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sizeof(*dataset)` in your call to `qsort()`?

Comment: `flow_data* dataset`, so `dataset` is a *pointer*. Now where you use  `qsort(dataset, total, sizeof(dataset), num_compare);` that is equivalent to `qsort(dataset, total, sizeof(a_pointer), num_compare);` You need to dereference `dataset` as @squeamishossifrage noted above.

Comment: Would the solution below be an adequate change?

Comment: @tobytobias Yes, because `sizeof(*dataset) == sizeof(flow_data)`. But you should use `sizeof(*dataset)`, as this makes your code more legible (because there's no need to check that `flow_data` is the correct type) and easier to maintain (because you can adapt this code to work with a different data type more easily).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
qsort(dataset, total, sizeof(dataset), num_compare);
```

To

```
qsort(dataset, total, sizeof(flow_data), num_compare);
```

Or

```
qsort(dataset, total, sizeof(*dataset), num_compare);
```

Because size of the pointer is not always the same as the size of the structure.